# Mirror one cell throughout column if secondary column is blank utilizing one formula

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently redoing my budget sheet in order to make it more user friendly.
**How its set up**
I have a script that makes it so whenever you change the name of a TAB (sheet) it will change the Header on cell "A1"
in order for the ledger to work, for each transaction in column C,D I need it to tell me what book (header) it is in the B column.
**I've used**
`=REPT("header",C5<>"")` however this requires manual input for the name and requires the formula to be posted throughout each cell in column B.
**=$A$1** solves the manual input issue but again requires to be in each cell and repeats if the cell is blank.
Sadly I don't understand how to combine formulas.
**to sum it up**
I need to mirror the text of A1 in cells B4:B if cells C5:C & D5:D are populated with only one formula- to ensure there is no accidental deletion:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Delete everything from B4:B and then place this in B4:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(C4:C="",,A1))`